# Difference between Email Address and Email Services Address - Email2Case

Tags: case, email2case

I have configured Email2Case in my dev org as shown below. I would like to understand the difference between **"Ëmail Address"** and **"Ëmail Services Address"** and can I send an email to the service address directly to create a Case?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sethu

From the doc on the page:

> Define email addresses on your email system for case submissions.
>   Create email routing addresses that include the addresses defined for cases.
>   **Configure your email system to forward case submissions to the Email Services Address provided to you by Salesforce.**

Basically, the EmailAddress field is the email address your customers will use to send you cases; This would be an email address known to your company's mail server. Your mail server needs to have a forwarding rule to take any inbound email to `support@mycompany.com` and send it to an inbound email address at Salesforce - as it is SFDC that actually processes the incoming email (to create the Case and handle threaded conversations)

If you don't personally manage your company's email administration, you'll have to get those folks involved

As best practice, set up different emailAddresses for your sandbox(es) and PROD - each will have a different EmailServicesAddress - this will let you test this setup before rolling out to PROD.  Hence your mailsystem admin will have to configure multiple rules -- like

`mysandbox-support@mycompany.com` forwards to the sandbox's emailservices address whereas `support@mycompany.com` forwards to the PROD email services address