# Org-wide email address not shown correctly in email received by customer

Tags: email, case, servicecloud

We have an org-wide email address set up that's being used in outgoing email communication on cases in Service Cloud. For some reason, one of our customers is seeing a salesforce email address instead (ending in `@2vamea4dqion.b-kz04eac.eu2.bnc.salesforce.com`) even though the outgoing address on the sent email in Salesforce is correct.

When testing the email functionality myself, the email address shows up correctly. What could be causing the org-wide email address to not show up as intended? Is it something on our end that I might have missed or can this be caused by the email service used by the customer?

Comment: It seems that the customer must have an email service configuration set up such that routed email addresses aren't seen (I assume for extra security purposes). This is because the customer is seeing the email2case services address, instead of the routed email address. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56971/difference-between-email-address-and-email-services-address-email2case

Comment: @AndyHitchings The email address that the customer was seeing is not the Email Services Address listed in our Email2Case settings (that one ends in `.eu2.case.salesforce.com`). Is it possible that the org-wide email itself uses a different routing address?

Comment: normally, to get rid of the `via xxxx.salesforce.com`, you have to set up email relaying. I would look there. That said, @AndyHitchings may be referring to the same thing when he used the word 'routed'